# How Xcode Test Navigator can show Google Tests in a pure C++ Project

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm using Xcode in my C++ project, but I haven't found how to show my unit tests in the Test Navigator. For testing I'm using Google Tests and this is a pure C++ project... no Objective C/C++ at all.

Answer (score 0):

[Google toolbox for Mac](https://github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac/blob/master/UnitTesting/GTMGoogleTestRunner.mm) contains custom test runner for Xcode which according to documentation will report results to Xcode Test UI